# How to capture button text (for the button user pressed) in adaptive cards

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

Technology :-

Nodejs Sdk for bot builder version 3
I have chat bot with MS teams and Cortana channel

I am trying to see if there a way to capture what buttons user has click on the adaptive card being presented . Most likely I am interested on text on the button so I can run some analytics.

My card has a button with "type": "Action.ShowCard", something similar to this sample https://adaptivecards.io/samples/ActivityUpdate.html

where let's just say I want to capture of user click on 'Comment' & 'Set due date' buttons.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

You won't see an obvious answer. The renderer handles showcard. But - for analytics you can use an Action.Submit. Your bot will get a Value on the message. You can then do your analytics, and show another card with a different layout.

Also, you might be able to use "a tracking pixel" approach (don't know, haven't tried), or implicitly gather stats if any of the stuff on the shown card is interacted with (that would come through as message text or value).

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by 

'Your bot will get a Value on the message. You can then do your analytics, and show another card with a different layout.'

If I'm following you right you are suggesting to do something like follows where I will populate value of Action.ShowCard & have submit to close the car ? the we can do session.value or something to make sure button for Action.ShowCard was clicked ?

Comment: If you modify the flow to use an Action.Submit instead of a ShowCard, you will get input set back to your bot.  If you keep using ShowCard, you need other tricks.  For example the embedded card can include an image that theoretically would load only when the card is shown (magic pixel). Then your web server watches for the download of that image (for analytics).

Comment: I have to use ShowCard because I don't want to have user clicked submit button. Reason being my card is giving information back to user show in this case ShowCard makes more sense over Submit where I will have to use Input.Text with some pre populated value. 

Plus analytics is not for the info (text fields , TextBlock value ) it's for which button out of 3 buttons clicked.

Comment: Ok. But showcard is implemented by the channelrender, and you have no control over that. On most surfaces, the Cortana renders implement show cards as hidden divs with a default js to flip the ccs display property in resposne to a click. You cannot intercept this, nor inject js, as that would be a massive security hole. What you can do is use Microsoft feedback hub to as for various channel developers to add such hooks for analytics in a nice way.